# How do I create form for SQLite?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, sqlite

I created a SQLite database with SQLite Manager extension in Firefox.

Now only need to create a form to insert, edit data. Because the Grid is very bad edit BLOB fields containing large texts.

I searched the Internet and found none simple program that creates the form. Any tips?

My database has only two fields: Name (text) and description (BLOB)

I am Beginner to SQL, I understand a little about Database, SQLite chose to not need to use any software or server dependent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite Manager is a tool for creating and managing SQLite database files. It is not a replacement for graphical database software like Microsoft Access or FileMaker.

SQLite cannot be used standalone; it is a library, not an application. You will need to choose another tool to accomplish this task.

Comment: I understand you're saying that with FileMaker program I can open my SQLite file that I created and then create a form like I have seen the images from FileMaker to Google? http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Publication/v4/66/86/26/66862612-0785-cbb9-6452-74841687e1b3/FileMaker_pro_12-2_original.480x480-75.jpg

Comment: No, you cannot. FileMaker is an entirely different application.

Comment: His comments helped, I liked to test FireMaker I did not know. But of course it is not meant for me. But how do you know what I want to do, only lacking to say whether there is any program that does this. In case you know any